# How to create a form in ZF2 using the fieldsets, validators, strategies and the "Element Collections"

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have spent a week to understand how to create a form in Zend Framework 2 using the fieldset and the element collection in order to use the right validator and a good field strategy.

I am trying to create an EAV (Entity, Attribute, Value) structure in my [Open Source Project](https://github.com/shinesoftware/shineisp2/tree/master/module/Product) but I have some difficulty with the Validators and strategies.

I am creating the Product management in my software where the fields of the form are described within the [attributes](http://snipet.co.uk/rM) table

The ProductForm is:

```
namespace ProductAdmin\Form;
use Product\Entity\Product;

use Zend\Form\Annotation\InputFilter;

use Zend\InputFilter\Input;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;
use Base\Hydrator\Strategy\DateTimeStrategy;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator;

class ProductForm extends Form
{

    public function init ()
    {
        $hydrator = new ClassMethods();
        // $hydrator->addStrategy('createdat', new DateTimeStrategy()); This is just an old strategy test for the first form field level.

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setHydrator($hydrator)->setObject(new \Product\Entity\Product());

        $this->add(array('type' => 'hidden', 'name' => 'type_id'));
        $this->add(array('type' => 'hidden', 'name' => 'attribute_set_id'));

        $this->add(
                array('name' => 'submit', 
                        'attributes' => array('type' => 'submit', 
                                'class' => 'btn btn-success', 
                                'value' => _('Save'))));
        $this->add(
                array('name' => 'id', 
                        'attributes' => array('type' => 'hidden')));
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the attribute form
     *
     * @param $attributes array           
     * @return \ProductAdmin\Form\ProductForm
     */
    public function createAttributesElements (array $attributes)
    {
        $customHydrator = new Hydrator\ClassMethods();
        $parentFilter = new \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter();
        $filterChain = new \Zend\Filter\FilterChain();
        $fieldset = new \Zend\Form\Fieldset('attributes');
        $fieldset->setFormFactory($this->getFormFactory()); // thanks to jurians #zftalk irc
        $fieldInput = null;

        $inputFilter = new \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $dateformat = "";
            $name = $attribute->getName();
            $label = $attribute->getLabel() ? $attribute->getLabel() : "-";
            $input = $attribute->getInput() ? $attribute->getInput() : "text";
            $type = $attribute->getType() ? $attribute->getType() : "string";
            $isRequired = $attribute->getIsRequired();
            $sourceModel = $attribute->getSourceModel();
            $filters = $attribute->getFilters();
            $cssStyles = $attribute->getCss();

            $filterChain->attachByName('null'); // set as default

            $typeSource = !empty($sourceModel) ? $sourceModel : $input;

            // Handle the dates
            if(!empty($type) && $type == "datetime"){
                $customHydrator->addStrategy($name, new DateTimeStrategy());
                $typeSource = 'Zend\Form\Element\DateTime';
                $dateformat = "d/m/Y";
            }

            $fieldset->add(
                      array('type' => $typeSource, 
                            'name' => $name, 
                            'attributes' => array(
                                        'id' => $name,
                                        'class' => 'form-control ' . $cssStyles,
                                    ), 
                            'options' => array('label' => _($label), 'format' => $dateformat)
                        )
            );

            $fieldInput = new \Zend\InputFilter\Input($name);
            $fieldInput->setRequired($isRequired);

            // handle the filters preferences of the attribute
            if(!empty($filters)){
                $filters = json_decode($filters, true);
                foreach ($filters as $filter){
                    $filterChain->attachByName($filter); 
                }
            }

            $fieldInput->setFilterChain($filterChain);
            $inputFilter->add($fieldInput);

        }

        $fieldset->setHydrator($customHydrator);
        $this->add($fieldset);
        $parentFilter->add($inputFilter, 'attributes'); // thanks to GeeH #zftalk irc
        $this->setInputFilter($parentFilter);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This is the Strategy class:

```
class DateTimeStrategy extends DefaultStrategy
{

    /**
     * Convert the database date field in the specific date format 
     * 
     * @see Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\Strategy.StrategyInterface::extract()
     */
    public function extract ($value)
    {
        $date = new \DateTime();

        // Check the date in this format Y-m-d H:i:s
        $validator = new \Zend\Validator\Date(array (
                'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                'locale' => 'it'
        ));

        if ($validator->isValid($value)) {
            $thedate = $date->createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value);
            $value = $thedate->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
        }

        // Check the date in this format Y-m-d
        $validator = new \Zend\Validator\Date(array (
                'format' => 'Y-m-d',
                'locale' => 'it'
        ));

        if ($validator->isValid($value)) {
            $thedate = $date->createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value);
            $value = $thedate->format('d/m/Y');
        }

        $pos = strpos($value, "-00");

        if($pos !== false){
            $thedate = $date->createFromFormat('Y-m-00', $value);
            $value = $thedate->format('m/Y');
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the date format from the post data array to the database format value
     * 
     * @see Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\Strategy.StrategyInterface::hydrate()
     */
    public function hydrate ($value)
    {
        if (is_string($value) && "" === $value) {
            $value = null;
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            $date = new \DateTime();
            $validator = new \Zend\Validator\Date(array ( 
                    'format' => 'd/m/Y', 
                    'locale' => 'it'
            ));
            if ($validator->isValid($value)) {
                $thedate = $date->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value);
                $value = $thedate->format('Y-m-d');
            }

            if(strlen($value) == 7){
                $thedate = $date->createFromFormat('m/Y', $value);
                if($thedate){
                    $value = $thedate->format('Y-m-00');
                }
            }
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

When I attach a Validator, for instance to the Datetime field, and then I post the data entered in the form, the result is this:

```
object(Product\Entity\Product)[917]
  public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  public 'uid' => null
  public 'type_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'attribute_set_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'attributes' => 
    array (size=12)
      'description' => string 'test' (length=4)
      'metadescription' => null
      'metakeyword' => null
      'name' => string 'hosting' (length=7)
      'news_from_date' => string '29/06/2014' (length=10)
      'news_to_date' => null
      'price' => string '10.5' (length=4)
      'short_description' => string 'test' (length=4)
      'sku' => string 'hst-01' (length=6)
      'special_price' => null
      'status' => string '1' (length=1)
      'urlkey' => string 'hosting' (length=7)
  public 'createdat' => null
  public 'updatedat' => null
```

As you can see the date has been posted without the correct format, ready to be inserted into the db table. The right date format must be yyyy-mm-dd.

This is the compiled form with all the attributes rendered.
[image]

Where is my error?

Comment: Is it not your hydration strategy (commented out) that would be responsible for setting the default date? `$hydrator->addStrategy('createdat', new DateTimeStrategy())`

Comment: No @AlexP it is not. That strategy is an old test and furthermore it is at the first level of the form. What I need to solve is the "sub-fieldset" called "attributes". Look at http://snipet.co.uk/B6 at the record number 8. This record creates the date input text field within the form. See the screenshot posted too. thanks

Comment: I think your problem is with your hydrator not transforming your date to a new `datetime` with `yyyy-mm-dd` format. The validator is just checking your input if it matches your format. Validators will not change any data they get, as that is not their work. So you should check out your `Base\Hydrator\Strategy\DateTimeStrategy` `hydrate($value)` if it does any transformation. With the code you provided it doesn't look that way at all. So I suggest you do a little bit of debugging and see what happens exactly at your `DateTimeStrategy`.

Comment: Hi @Kudo this is the strategy class: http://goo.gl/BJYQgq It works as well in the whole project. I have debugged for days without any result. Seems that I need to set an object class to the "dynamic fieldset" in order to use the strategy: http://goo.gl/JumZw3